# Custom Shortcode Gallery Ignoring Enqueue'd CSS and JS files

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor, nanogallery

I am attempting to bring in my own image gallery through a shortcode so I can add it to an Elementor widget. Currently, I have everything done, but I am not getting any styling or images showing up for this gallery. Both the css file and the js file are loading in the browser. All the HTML for the gallery is loading as well, however I am not seeing any styling or images appearing.

Here is the shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'selected_works_gallery', function () {
    ob_start();?>

    <div id = "selected_works_gallery" data-nanogallery2 = '{ "thumbnailWidth": "auto", "thumbnailHeight": 200}'>
        <?php foreach (get_field('selected_works') as $image): ?>
        
        <a href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']?>" data-ngthumb="<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']?>">Image tagline</a>
        
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $out;
} );
```

The enqueueing:

```
function enqueue_custom_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'nanogallery2', esc_url_raw('https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css'), array(), null );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_styles');

function enqueue_custom_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nanogallery2_js', esc_url_raw('https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js'), false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
```

My only guesses are:

- the HTML is so buried in divs that the enqueued files can't select the tags
- something with the priority (really don't understand this, they are all just set to default)
- WordPress has issues with outside files being enqueued
- I have to do something with Elementor to get this gallery to work properly
- NanoGallery2 is just not meant for this or I set it up wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by bringing the js and css files into the local files. Nanogallery needed Jquery to work and it was loading after it. I just enqueue'd Jquery before my own scripts and the gallery works fine.